# Unable to activate type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine when starting app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Asp.net core 2.1

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (this.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=GenericController}/{action=Get}");
    });
}
```

Error message:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to activate type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine'. The following
>   constructors are ambiguous: Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPageFactoryProvider,
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPageActivator,
>   System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions],
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProject,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory,
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource) Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPageFactoryProvider,
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPageActivator,
>   System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions],
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectFileSystem,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory,
>   System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with upgrading. I'm guessing you might have recently upgraded from 1.x?

I would try this:

1. Nuget packages -> Make sure your only "Web"-related installed packages are Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.NETCore.App. You'll probably have some CodeGeneration package as well, which shouldn't be a concern. Versions should be around 2.1.
2. Make sure your .csproj is cleared from everything mentioned in this migration guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1
3. A final hail mary is clearing any weird stuff in any .config files and/or reinstalling the Nuget-packages. (And in worst case, check all your references for any non 2.1 web-related DLLs)

Comment: I created my project in beta-5 and have been migrating it ever since.  In my case I had this line in my startup.cs since beta-8 or rc-1:
`services.AddSingleton<IRazorViewEngine, RazorViewEngine>();`
Removing this fixed my issue.